# Uniform convergence of $\sum -\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)^2}$ over a closed and bounded subinterval of $[0,2 \pi]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

As mentioned in the title, I want to study the uniform convergence of the following series.
$\sum -\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)^2}$ for $x\in[a,b]$ where $0<a<b<2\pi$

I try to apply $M$-test but I am get $\left|\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{\log(n)^2}$

As $\sum \frac{1}{\log(n)^2}$ diverge, I am going nowhere.

Could anyone help me or giving me some hints?

Thank you very much for reading my passage.

Comment: summation by parts using that $\Sigma {\sin(nx)}=O(\frac{2\pi}{a}), 0<a<x<b < 2\pi$

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence):

- $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\sin(nx)\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ is [uniformly bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro);
- the sequence $\left(\frac1{\log^2n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}}$ is monotonic;
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log^2n}=0$.